# Interface for Cbc - COIN-OR

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, or-tools, open-source

I would like to code some IP/MIP models in python and test them with an open-source solver. As of now, I only know the **Cbc - COIN-OR** open-source solver.

I have already tried the or-tools interface, unfortunately, its capabilities are restricted (e.g., linear expressions are not possible).

I have also tried to install the **COIN-OR CyLP** Interface both in Win10 and Linux Ubuntu without any success.

Are there any interfaces that offer an **OR-Tools** similar experience?

Comment: PuLP (https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/) is a very (very) good option.

Comment: The MiniZinc Interface is also quite powerful. Moreover, there is in coursera a course about it https://www.coursera.org/learn/basic-modeling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several packages I can think of with an interface to CBC:

- [Pyomo](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/solving_pyomo_models.html)
- [PuLP](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/)
- [MIP](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I also found MiniZinc although it only has Constraint Programming examples. Which one of the three you mentioned would you recommend?

Comment: Also from the three interfaces, you mentioned the MIP is beautifully documented.

Comment: I came to know Pulp before the other two and I've used it more. Also, Pulp syntax resembles gurobi which definitely made it easier for me and I think it's easy to learn for anyone. Pyomo is definitely the richest, with object-oriented style and feel, and well maintained. So, I incline to say it's the most robust. I've not had the chance to use MIP myself and I heard about it from others, but I agree with your statement about its documentation.