# Open Source MILP software for Python with user-friendly API to define the optimization problem

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, python, assignment-problem

Following the accepted answer to

[Assignment problem where assignments must be done sequentially](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/assignment-problem-where-assignments-must-be-done-sequentially/)

I would like to write a Python script which can solve the problem defined there. It's a Mixed Integer Linear Programming problem, thus I need an Open Source MILP solver, and a modeler. The constraints are probably very simple for you guys, but since I'm not familiar with MILP, it would be great if the modeler had an intuitive, easy to use API. Can you indicate me a Python modeler and solver which I can use to solve the problem? If you could also help me describing the MILP problem in the question above, using the modeler API, that would be great.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: [I've formulated my optimization model; now what?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/ive-formulated-my-optimization-model-now-what). You'll get to know commercial and open-source solvers, each with a Python API. And if you're looking for packages that call open-source solvers, check out this question: [Interface for Cbc - COIN-OR](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3303/interface-for-cbc-coin-or)

Comment: In my opinion PuLP is outstanding : https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/

Comment: All the commercial solves have Python interfaces. I think [mosek](https://mosek.com) is a good one since I build it.

Comment: The [MIPCL](http://mipcl-cpp.appspot.com) solver has a nice interface on python and easy to use. I think easier than other solvers with good performance.

Comment: I didn't know that for MIP codes, there is a separation between modeling language and solver. Also, I'm not interested in commercial software. I edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: HiGHS has the best truly open-source MIP solver, and a limited Python interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find Pulp is extremely easy to use, versatile and has good performance. Check it out here: https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/solvers.html

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a Python user, but I've heard good things about [Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/), which is an open-source modeling language. In addition to Pyomo, you would need a solver program (from among those they support), but you would not need to worry about any syntax issues related to the solver.

Comment: I second this, Pyomo is great and automatically connects to any solver with an ASL interface (which is most of the COIN-OR stuff).

Answer (score 4):

A more recent alternative is [Python-MIP](https://www.python-mip.com/). It has built-in support of [COIN-OR CBC](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc). In addition, right now it supports one commercial solver, namely Gurobi. According to its website, it provides access to advanced solver features like cut generation, lazy constraints, MIP starts and solution pools. Since Python-MIP is mentioned on the COIN-OR [projects webpage](https://www.coin-or.org/projects/), it seems that Python-MIP is going to be open source in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, PULP is one of the open source solver. Apart from this, the best MILP solver available in open source is preferably offered in SCIP optimization suite. I think Google OR tools are built using SCIP only. Moreover, you can refer to [COIN-OR](https://www.coin-or.org/) where researchers from ORMS society have maintained their projects.

Comment: SCIP is not open source. You cannot use it freely for commercial use for instance. See the [license agreement](https://scip.zib.de/index.php#license).

Comment: Pulp is actually not a solver but a modeling framework - will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: The HiGHS MIP solver is now as good as SCIP, and is truly open source.